# MS Powerpoint table and shape group problem

Tags: powerpoint

I can't group table and shape in MS Powerpoint. Is there any way to group these part. If this is the case then I can move my table and shape together with one click.

I tried in many ways but I can't find any ways. Please help me.

Comment: Tables can't be grouped. The same is true of placeholders.